# Keeping the largest map values?

Tags: java, collections

I have a Map of which I am trying to keep only the n amount of highest values, and then placing these values in a list (or alternatively, if possible deleting everything else from the map).

This is what I have tried so far, but it did not work.It wasn't limited to only n amount of values.

```
 double[] array = new double[n];
 List <String> finalwords= new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String word: map.keySet()){
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if(map.get(word) > array[i]){
                array[i] = map.get(word);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(String word: map.keySet()){
        for(int i=0; i<array .length; i++){
            if(map.get(word)>= array[i]) {
                finalwords.add(word);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I even cannot understand what this code suppose to do, but for sure it is very far from what you tried to describe in question

Comment: ok, I finally see your intent, why do you think it should work at all? You have at least 2 huge problems with this algorithm: 1. you're storing of maximal N values is wrong, write several unit tests to prove it 2. if several words have the same value - all of them will be added, this is why you have more than N words

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend you to use `TreeMap`, which maintains the order between items. When the size of the map exceeds the capacity, I think you can remove the smallest items from the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort based on values, rather than keys, and you want to retain key value pairs with the highest values, then you can take an entryList and sort it with a custom Comparator. In the example below I used 3 for the n to keep.

```
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> kv = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(kv, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            return (o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue()));
        }
    });

    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> e: kv.subList(kv.size()-3, kv.size())) {
        System.out.println("e:" + e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're using Java 8, you can also use streams to filter the map as follows:

```
int max = 3; // Your limit 

// retainAll will remove entries where the key is not in the supplied set 
map.keySet().retainAll(                
    map.entrySet().stream()
        // Sort by values in descending order
        .sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue()))      
        // Limit results and return set of keys
        .limit(max).map(a -> a.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toSet()) 
);
```